# Bugs with using custom coding and Twitter's Alert plugin with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, filtering

I have a filter I am using based off of Twitter's Alert, Collapse, and Modal Plugin.  The conflict comes with using the Alert plugin and my custom code to get it to function how it should.

The filter functions like a sort, when clicking a selection, it creates a field (in the case of the BCN and Account filters which are my problem children) within the sort menu below its heading.

EX: Clicking on accounts pulls up a modal window from there, the user selects an account name.  That name appears outside of the modal window and in the filter section below Account. The selection can be dismissed when clicking on the X beside it or dismiss all of them by clicking the reset button at the bottom.

This is where the bugs occur:

1. After selecting one account name, it requires a double click for each subsequent selection made.  It should only require one click
2. When clicking on an account selection (several), dismissing it via the X, then reclicking the same option tha that was previously selected causes all dismissed
   selections to appear in the filter section.

My question is how to tamper out the bugs.  I am open to using another method that isn't the alert plugin so long as it works properly.

Link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/rsxavior/ccvEw/2/